# How to calculate the distance between two points, for many consequent points, within groups in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `df`

```
       id             xx            yy  time
0       1  553343.041098  4.178420e+06     1
1       1  553343.069815  4.178415e+06     2
2       1  553343.069815  4.178415e+06     3
3       2  553343.950755  4.178415e+06     1
4       2  553341.343829  4.178410e+06     6
```

The `xx` and `yy` is the position of each `id` at a certain point in `time`.

I would like to create an extra column in this `df`, which will be the difference in distance from one point of time to another (going from the smallest value of `time` to the next bigger, to the next bigger one etc), within the `id` group.

Is there a Pythonic way of doing so ?

Comment: What are your expected results? What have you tried? Could you share the code for generating your example df please?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás Isnt clear what the expected results should be ? You can as well use `pd.read_clipboard()` to get the example `df`

Comment: @quant "Isnt clear what the expected results should be " - if it was clear, then no one would be asking for clarification. You should always include the expected output for your sample data to help answerers better understand what you want without having to make guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below.

I didn't do `df['distance_meters']` because it is straight forward.

```
df['xx_diff']=df.groupby('id')['xx'].diff()**2
df['yy_diff']=df.groupby('id')['yy'].diff()**2
```

If you don't need ['xx_diff'] & ['yy_diff'] columns in your dataframe, you can directly use the code below.

```
df['distance']= np.sqrt(df.groupby('id')['xx'].diff()**2+df.groupby('id')['yy'].diff()**2)
```

**Output**

```
    id            xx         yy time    xx_diff3    yy_diff3    distance
0   1   553343.041098   4178420.0   1   NaN            NaN      NaN
1   1   553343.069815   4178415.0   2   0.000825       25.0     5.000082
2   1   553343.069815   4178415.0   3   0.000000       0.0      0.000000
3   2   553343.950755   4178415.0   1   NaN            NaN      NaN
4   2   553341.343829   4178410.0   6   6.796063      25.0      5.638800
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a more efficient way to do this, but here is a solution:

```
import numpy as np
df['xx_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['xx'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: (x[1] - x[0])**2).reset_index(drop=True)
df['yy_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['yy'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: (x[1] - x[0])**2).reset_index(drop=True)
df['distance_meters'] = np.sqrt(df['xx_diff'] + df['yy_diff'])
```

A more pythonic answer will be accepted :)

Comment: Why not include this as part of your question? It shows what you've tried and stops others making the same suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def calc_distance(values):
    values.sort_values('id', inplace = True)
    values['distance_diff'] = 0
    values.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for i in range(values.shape[0]-1):
        p1 = list(values.loc[i, ['xx', 'yy']])
        p2 = list(values.loc[i+1, ['xx', 'yy']])
        values.loc[i,'distance_diff'] = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2))
    return values

lt = []
lt.append(df.groupby(['id']).apply(calc_distance))
print(pd.concat(lt, ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
   id             xx         yy  time  distance_diff
0   1  553343.041098  4178420.0     1       5.000082
1   1  553343.069815  4178415.0     2       0.000000
2   1  553343.069815  4178415.0     3       0.000000
3   2  553343.950755  4178415.0     1       5.638800
4   2  553341.343829  4178410.0     6       0.000000
```